# What are the math fonts used in this page

Tags: fonts, xetex, math-fonts

I would like to use the nice fonts (text + math) of the following document (from the Encyclopedia of Mathematical Physics).
I tried [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but without a convenient result.
[image: page]

I used pdffonts command and I get a huge list of embedded fonts (strange ones as OAAALF+AdvP4E79...) and some recognizable ones (Helvetica, Sabon-Italic, CASLONOPENFACE-Thin). I ddin't get the used mathematical fonts.
the nice answers given here [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)
do not cover math fonts!

> Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you have the pdf so should be able to list the fonts used, no need to make us guess from a image.

Comment: If you can't share the pdf (copyright reasons) you could at least show the output of `pdffonts`. Right now you are just asking us to guess...

Comment: Well, the sans-serif font is Helvetica obviously. The serif font used for the text is Sabon and for the math part, I would say, they used Sabon where possible and some other fonts for the glyphs that are not included in the font, such as the Greek letters. The small nu actually looks a lot like Computer Modern.

Comment: All the Greek (including the partial) looks like Computer Modern.  If you can find an italic text passage, compare the letters to the math; if they match, you've got your answer. Similarly with digits.